# C++ Function Syntax

Tags: c++, function, c++11, syntax, c++14

In this example,

```
#include "crow.h"

int main(){
  crow::SimpleApp app;

  CROW_ROUTE(app, "/")([](){
    return "Hello world";
  });
app.port(18080).multithreaded().run();
}
```

What does this snippet `([](){` refer to ?

I cannot seem to find any reference to this in the C++ docs.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it starts with () however ?

Comment: The opening paren in front of `[]` is part of a function call; the matching closing paren is two lines down, after a brace. You have a lambda being passed as an argument to a function. In other words: `auto lambda = [](){...}; CROW_ROUTE(app, "/")(lambda);`